# Probability of $2$ people being together out of a group of $4$.

Tags: probability, combinations

There were $2$ people who wanted to be in a group together. Those $2$ people were in a pool of $4$ people. Someone would randomly select $2$ people in a row and those people would be in a group together. The remaining $2$ would also be in a group.

What the probability of those $2$ people who wanted to be in the same group actually being in the same group?

**What I tried**

Lets assume that the $2$ who want to be together are person A and B respectively and person C and D are the other $2$.

The probability of choosing person A and B is $\dfrac 14 \cdot \dfrac 13 = \dfrac 1{12}.$

Comment: You have calculated the number of ways to pair A and B when you pick A first. It is also possible to pair them picking B first.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We are placing the four people in two groups of two people.  Notice that person $A$ must be in a group with one of the other three people, of whom only one is person $B$.  Hence, the probability that persons $A$ and $B$ are placed in the same group is $1/3$.

Comment: I feel like you should get +5 just for being the only one noticing: "The remaining 2 would also be in a group." in the question :)

Comment: I noticed too, but he got there 45 seconds before I did, with the same logic, so I deleted my answer.

Comment: @Dan Uznanski, oh, right, I haven't read your answer since you deleted it immediately.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig The logic makes sense to me, but how can I mathematically  express this?

Comment: The argument stated above is a valid mathematical argument.  Alternatively, observe that there are $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ ways to choose two people to serve in a group.  However, this counts each group twice, once when we select two people to serve in the group and once when we choose its complement.  To see this, observe that if we choose $A$ and $B$ to be in a group, the other group is $C$ and $D$ and that if we choose $C$ and $D$ to be in a group, the other group is $A$ and $B$.  Hence, the number of distinguishable outcomes is $\frac{1}{2} \binom{4}{2} = 3$, of which only one is desired.

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is that you are considering only one possibility where A and B end up in the same group. What are the others?

Another approach can be direct counting. There are total of $4!$ possible arrangements, out of which $2\cdot 1$ that begin with AB and $2\cdot 1$ that begin with BA, but also $2\cdot 1$ that end in AB and $2\cdot 1$ that end in BA, so the probability is $\dfrac{2+2+2+2}{24} = \dfrac 13$.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for solving this could be

Let's hypothetically group those two people whom you want to be together and assume them as single object .

Now, we have 1 object and two other people.

Total 3 things .

So what is probability of choosing 1 from 3 that is 1/3